# Filter is working but they overwrite each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, database, html-table

I was searching in two column at a time, and it's not give me correct result.
The problem is that they overwrite each other. I would appreciate any suggestions on how to apply second filter only to the results of the first one, not to the entire dataset.

Thank you!
This is the input types

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
<input type="text" id="myInput1" onkeyup="myFunction1()" placeholder="Search for country.." title="Type in a country">
```

And this is the script:

```
function myFunction1() {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
    input document.getElementById("myInput1") filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        if (td) {
            if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
}

function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
    input document.getElementById("myInput") filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
        if (td) {
            if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the link: https://onlinegdb.com/H153ldRYf

Comment: Your question does not explain you problem

Comment: This seems like a "debug this for me please" question. Have you tried debugging? What input data did you use, and what output did you expect?

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/H153ldRYf ...click on this link here is the code.. . if i searching in name column so its is working . but when i searching in column country at same time so the result is not match as name column means its searching in whole table again .

Comment: both name and country column searching is working .but when i m searching in name column "Alfreds" and then i am searching in country column "uk" so name "Alfreds" is gone and result is different.

Comment: are bta do koi yar :(